# How to left outer join use SQLAlchemy Association Object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have three table roles, pages and role_pages. I try to use Association Class with extra data in association table as in the following link https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html. And this is my model class.

```
class RolePage(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'role_pages'
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.role_id'), primary_key=True)
    page_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('pages.page_id'), primary_key=True)
    can_readed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    can_created = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    can_updated = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    can_deleted = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    can_submited = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    can_approved = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    arole = db.relationship('Role', back_populates='pages')
    apage = db.relationship('Page', back_populates='roles')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<RolePage ({self.role_id}, {self.page_id}, {self.can_readed}, {self.can_created})>'


class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True, nullable=True)
    pages = db.relationship('RolePage', back_populates='arole')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Role {self.name}>'


class Page(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pages'
    page_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True, nullable=True)
    roles = db.relationship('RolePage', back_populates='apage')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Page {self.name}>'
```

My problem is, I want to query use left join, like query I make in sql:

```
select * from pages p
left join role_pages rp on rp.page_id = p.page_id and rp.role_id = 2 
left join roles r on r.role_id = rp.role_id;
```

I try to query `left join` table use ORM.

```
Page.query\
    .outerjoin(RolePage, and_(RolePage.role_id==id))\
    .all()
```

But the `left join` not work. What the best way to use `left join` like my problem in sqlalchemy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the documentation from SQLAlchemy and many forums. I got the answer. To query use `left join` we can use `isouter=True` or `.outerjoin()`.
And in my case I use flask-sqlalchemy so to select column I use `.with_entities()`, because I have column with same name I use `.label()` to create alias. And this is my SQLALchemy code:

```
pages = Page.query\
                .with_entities(\
                    Page.page_id,\
                    Page.name.label('page_name'),\
                    Role.role_id,\
                    Role.name.label('role_name'),\
                    RolePage.can_readed,\
                    RolePage.can_created,\
                    RolePage.can_updated,\
                    RolePage.can_deleted,\
                    RolePage.can_submited,\
                    RolePage.can_approved,\
                    )\
                .join(RolePage,\
                (Page.page_id==RolePage.page_id) &
                (RolePage.role_id==id), isouter=True)\
                .join(Role, Role.role_id==RolePage.role_id, isouter=True)
```

And this solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

To use ORM, create a session
Please refer to that document

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html

```
from sqlalchemy import and_

q = session.query(Page, RolePage, Role) \
        .outerjoin(RolePage, and_(RolePage.page_id == Page.page_id, Rolepage.role_id == 2)) \
        .outerjoin(Role, Role.role_id == RolePage.role_id)

for _page, _role_page, _role in q:
    print(_page, _role_page, _role)
```

Comment: Thanks @KiDoo Song, this answer adds to my insight.